Why is template parent class member variable not visible in derived template class scope?
In the following code, class B inherits from class A using the CRTP pattern, i.e. more specifically, class B inherits from class A<B>.
Important to this question: note that function B::implementation() uses parent member variable A<B>::i_:
// a.h

#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

#include <iostream>

template<typename Derived>
struct A {
  void interface() {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
    static_cast<Derived*>(this)->implementation();
  }

  int i_{42};
};

#endif

// b.h

#ifndef B_H
#define B_H

#include "a.h"

#include <iostream>

class B : public A<B> {
public:
  void implementation() {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << ": " << i_ << "\n";
  }
};

#endif

// main.cpp

#include "b.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  B().interface();

  return 0;
}

Compilation/execution:
$ g++ --version && g++ -g ./main.cpp && ./a.out
g++ (Ubuntu 13.2.0-23ubuntu4) 13.2.0
Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

void A<Derived>::interface() [with Derived = B]
void B::implementation(): 42
$

I modify this class relationship by introducing class C<B> between class B and class A<C<B>>, i.e. class B now inherits from class C<B>, which inherits from class A<C<B>>.
Since class A and main.cpp are unmodified, below are only class C and the modified class B:
// c.h

#ifndef C_H
#define C_H

#include "a.h"

#include <iostream>

template<typename Derived>
class C : public A<C<Derived>> {
public:
  void implementation() {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << ": " << i_ << "\n";
    static_cast<Derived*>(this)->implementation();
  }
};

#endif

// b.h

#ifndef B_H
#define B_H

#include "c.h"

#include <iostream>

class B : public C<B> {
public:
  void implementation() {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << ": " << i_ << "\n";
  }
};

#endif

This time, when I compile, I get an error that i_ is not declared in the scope of class C:
$ g++ -g ./main.cpp && ./a.out
In file included from ./b.h:6,
                 from ./main.cpp:3:
./c.h: In member function ‘void C<Derived>::implementation()’:
./c.h:12:49: error: ‘i_’ was not declared in this scope
   12 |     std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << ": " << i_ << "\n";
      |                                                 ^~
$

What gives?
Why is public variable int A<C<B>>::i_ not visible in the scope of derived class C<B>?

If I remove the reference to i_ in c.h, compilation succeeds, and execution runs as expected, which shows that A<C<B>>::i_ is visible in the scope of B, it's just not visible in the scope of C<B>:
// c.h

#ifndef C_H
#define C_H

#include "a.h"

template<typename Derived>
class C : public A<C<Derived>> {
public:
  void implementation() {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << ": " << /* i_ << */ "\n";
    static_cast<Derived*>(this)->implementation();
  }
};

#endif

$ g++ -g ./main.cpp && ./a.out
void A<Derived>::interface() [with Derived = C<B>]
void C<Derived>::implementation() [with Derived = B]:
void B::implementation(): 42
$ 

